# struts2 - How do request parameters get populated to corresponding fields in the action class?

Tags: struts2, struts, interceptor

If there is a request parameter '**name**' passed to an action, we can receive it in our **Action** class if we have a field named '**name**'. Which interceptor is responsible for doing this ? I looked at the code for `ParametersInterceptor`, but it only sets the parameters onto the **value stack**, not in corresponding fields of the action class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it only sets the parameters onto the value stack, not in
>   corresponding fields of the action class

There is just a little glitch in your reasoning: The action class is is at the top of the value stack! So com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor is responsible.

Answer (score 0):

As a piece of advice, though, I would suggest that you don't actually have a parameter named "name" on the action class, but rather move such fields from your action class into another class that will serve as your "model".  Then, have your action class implement the ModelDriven interface.  This will place the model class on the top of the ValueStack instead of the action class instance, and then the "name" parameter will map onto your model instance.

The separation of the model/data concerns into another class from the action/control concerns will make your code more readable and maintainable.  Of course, if there is only, say, a single param, then separating it into a separate class would be silly.  More than 2 or 3 params, though, and you will benefit from the separation.